# Cannot use malloc with struct data type?

Tags: c, struct

This is just part of a bigger code, but it's full of errors so I try to fix them one by one. When I try to use malloc on my pointer vector the line returns this error

> main.c|14|error: expected '{' before '*' token

Any resolutions?

```
   struct students {
       int group;
       char name[20];
       int grade;
   };

   int main()
   {
         struct students *ptr[100];
         int num, i, max=0;
         scanf("%d", &num);
         ptr = (struct*) malloc(num * sizeof(struct));
         if(ptr == NULL)
             {
              printf("error");
              exit(0);
             }
    }
```

Comment: You put `struct` where you should have put `struct students`.

Comment: `struct *` is a sytanx error. Maybe you meant `struct students *`.  BTW you can avoid this error by not casting malloc, which is redundant anyway, and not repeating the type in the `sizeof`.

Comment: `sizeof(struct students)`. Don't cast the return of malloc.

Comment: I get this now and I need to use heap vector in this exercise..
main.c|14|error: assignment to expression with array type

Comment: Note that `ptr` is the name of an array (of 100 pointers to `struct student`).  You can't assign directly to an array like that.  That's quite apart from the problem already identified with `sizeof(struct student)` missing the word `student`.  However, you need to rethink what you're trying to do more than just fixing that syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struct is reserved keyword for declaring/defining structures in C, it isn't variable, nor something you cant get size of it. You have declared struct students (according to your code, i think it should be student instead of students), now you have to define a variable and allocate space for 100 structs via a double pointer, the code should be something like this

```
   struct student {
       int group;
       char name[20];
       int grade;
   };

   int main()
   {
         struct student ** ptr;
         int num, i, max=0;
         scanf("%d", &num);
         ptr = malloc(num * sizeof(struct student));
         if(ptr == NULL)
             {
              printf("error");
              exit(0);
             }
    }
```

Now you can access individual students with array subscript

```
ptr[0]->grade = 20; // putting 20 in grade of first student
```

Also, there is no need for casting malloc result in C

Answer (score 0):

1. While using malloc for a 1D array, you should allocate a pointer, not an array of pointers as you have done.
2. While allocating you are using `sizeof(struct)`. The type here is `struct students` and you need `sizeof(struct students)`
3. Do not cast the result of malloc. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

The final code is

```
struct students *ptr;
ptr = malloc (num * sizeof(struct students));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of pointers to structure. You should allocate memory for them separately.

```
for(int i=0; i<100 && i<num; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct students));
    if(0 == ptr[i])
    {
        /* Handle this case. */
    }
}
/* Your code. */

/* At the end free the memory. */
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    if(0 != ptr[i])
    {
        free(ptr[i]);
        ptr[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

But I think you just wanted to allocate an array of struct students. In that case you just need one pointer.

```
struct students *ptr = 0;

/* You allocate memory and store it in that pointer. */
ptr = malloc(num * sizeof(struct students)); 
if(0 == ptr)
{
    /* Handle this case. */
}
```

You can access ith element of the array like `ptr[i]`. But add necessary checks and make sure `i < num`.

You need to free the allocated memory whenever you are done using the array.

```
if(0 != ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
    ptr = 0;
}
```